# How could I find the value of $x$ without squaring both sides given the equation $\sqrt{8} + \sqrt{18} = \sqrt{x}$?

Tags: radicals, radical-equations

Our class got a challenge question on a recent test, that no one has been able to figure out. We know $x = 50$, but everyone seems to get stuck when they simplify it to $5\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{x}$. Any help? Is this even possible?

Comment: Why *not* square both sides?

Comment: Well $\sqrt{2} (2 + 3) = \sqrt{2}\sqrt{x/2}$ so $5=\sqrt {\frac x2}$ so $\frac x2 = 25$.

Comment: how did you come up with that first step? @fleablood

Comment: MathJax works in the title, don't you know?

Comment: If you really want to avoid squaring at all, you could go from $5 \sqrt{2} = \sqrt{x}$ to $\sqrt{50} = \sqrt{x}$ and conclude that $x = 50$ because $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is injective.

Comment: Seriously?  $\sqrt 8 + \sqrt {18} = \sqrt x$ so $\sqrt{2*4} + \sqrt{2*9} = \sqrt x$ so $\sqrt{2} (\sqrt {4} + \sqrt { 9}) = \sqrt x$ so $\sqrt {4} + \sqrt {9} = \sqrt {\frac x2}$ so $2 + 3 =5 = \sqrt {\frac x2}$ so $25 = \frac x 2$.

Comment: Another way $\sqrt 8 + \sqrt 18 = \sqrt x$ so $\sqrt{8*2} + \sqrt{18*2} = \sqrt {2x}$ so $\sqrt 16 + \sqrt 36 = 4 + 6 = 10 =\sqrt {2x}$..  So $100 = 2x$.  ... I'm actually having a hard time seeing where your difficulty lies.  You you had a hard time simplyfying $5\sqrt 2 =\sqrt x$.  Well??? Whats to simplify.  Squar both sides and you get $5^2*2 = x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = 2y$.

Then $\sqrt{2*4} + \sqrt{2*9} = \sqrt{2y}$

So $\sqrt 2(\sqrt 4 + \sqrt 9) = \sqrt 2\sqrt y$

$2+3 =\sqrt y$

$5 = \sqrt y$

$y = 25$

$x = 50$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$5\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{x}\to \sqrt{50}=\sqrt{x}$$

the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is injective for $x\ge0$.

Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

You can just square both sides immediately, or you can simplify before squaring:

$$
\sqrt{8} + \sqrt{18} = \sqrt{x} \\
\sqrt{2\cdot 4} + \sqrt{2\cdot 9} = \sqrt{x} \\
2\sqrt{2} + 3\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{x} \\
5\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{x} \\
(5\sqrt{2})^2 = (\sqrt{x})^2 \\
5^2\cdot \sqrt{2}^2 = x \\
25\cdot 2 = x \\
50 = x
$$